# Last inserted ID with Jersey returning 0

Tags: java, mysql, jpa, jersey

I have a service returnin the last_inserted_id from my mysql database but I'am always getting 0 as response.
Whats the problem?

service code :

```
@GET
@Produces("text/plain")
@Path("lastindex")
public int getLastInsertKey() {

    Query q = getEntityManager().createNativeQuery("select last_insert_id() as lastindex");
    lastIndex= q.getFirstResult();
    return lastIndex;
}
```

Comment: Are you sure the value isn't 0?

Comment: @AnubianNoob yes I am. I call this method just after a successfull insertion.

Comment: Resolved ! I just had to call flush on entityManager after insertion and return the last inserted object's id.

Comment: Awesome! You should totally write that as an answer, as to help future visitors to the site (and to solidify your own learning too) :)

Comment: Thank you @Anubian for the  advice and attention.  I will write  a more detailed  answer.